# Resolve NetBIOS name on iOS

Tags: ios, network-programming, netbios

Is there any way on iOS to resolve `NetBIOS` name using IP address?

One could resolve `NetBIOS` name on a Mac using **terminal command:**

> smbutil -v status -ae

The smbutil is opensourced so you can find it here:
http://www.apple.com/opensource/ -> http://opensource.apple.com//source/smb/

And the same on GitHub:
https://github.com/unofficial-opensource-apple/smb

But the util extensively uses private and Mac OS-specific frameworks so Xcode couldn't even compile the source for iOS.

Comment: Have you tried isolating the Apple smb code to that needed only for name resolution? That looks to be substantially less code, just that needed to support `nbns_resolvename`: https://github.com/unofficial-opensource-apple/smb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nbns_resolvename

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to do a reverse DNS lookup, [gethostbyaddr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyaddr), because it looks like DNS, [gethostbyname](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname), is the only thing being used to go from NetBios name to IP.

Looking at the source from Apple, the [smbutil](https://opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-115/smbutil/status.c.auto.html) application in the 'status' mode first calls '[nb_resolvehost](https://opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-115/lib/smb/nb_net.c.auto.html)' which just uses 'gethostbyname' to get the IP address from NetBios name. 'gethostbyname' uses DNS under the hood:

```
nb_resolvehost_in(const char *name, struct sockaddr **dest)
{
    struct hostent* h;
    struct sockaddr_in *sinp;
    int len;

    h = gethostbyname(name);
    if (!h) {
        warnx("can't get server address `%s': ", name);
        herror(NULL);
        return ENETDOWN;
    }
    if (h->h_addrtype != AF_INET) {
        warnx("address for `%s' is not in the AF_INET family", name);
        return EAFNOSUPPORT;
    }
    if (h->h_length != 4) {
        warnx("address for `%s' has invalid length", name);
        return EAFNOSUPPORT;
    }
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    sinp = malloc(len);
    if (sinp == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;
    bzero(sinp, len);
    sinp->sin_len = len;
    sinp->sin_family = h->h_addrtype;
    memcpy(&sinp->sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr, 4);
    sinp->sin_port = htons(SMB_TCP_PORT);
    *dest = (struct sockaddr*)sinp;
    return 0;
}
```

After this call the 'smbutil status' then sends some sort of SMB query using the function '[nbns_getnodestatus](https://opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-115/lib/smb/nbns_rq.c.auto.html)' to the previously given IP address on the SMB port. From this query the command gets Workgroup and Servername (not sure which server this is referring to).

Comment: Can you please take look at this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679455)? Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue of getting host name from network scan of connected wi-fi? Other apps on App Store like Fing, Net Analyzer are able to get host name.

Comment: @ChintanShah if you are already enumerating IP addresses, you can just reverse DNS the addresses as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258464/getnameinfo-reverse-dns-lookup-ip-address-to-hostname-c-c?). A general warning though, enumerating the network can get your app flagged as malware, might want to look into multicast instead.